# Есть сверстаный контент, натянул 5 вертикальных линий на весь контент, и эффекты наведения не работают, как исправить?

Tags: вёрстка, frontend

есть верстка мне нужно на весь контент растянуть 5 вертикальных линий.
но проблема в том что все эффекты при наведения на блоков ссылок, кнопок и тд. не работают??? как это исправить ?

весь контент я обернул в один блок 'wrap' чтобы растянуть вертикальные линии на весь контент но эффекты наведения не работают потому что перекрывает блок с верт. линиями как это исправить ?

с z-index пробувал чет не работает (
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap_line{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    
}

.wrap_line .line{
    height: 30000px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background: rgba(61, 124, 246, 1);
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

если не нужно никак взаимодействовать с блоком линий, то можно добавить такое свойство:

```
.wrap { pointer-events: none; }
```